# pyenv-virtualenvwrapper not working: wont use pyenv shell or pyenv local settings

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pyenv, virtualenvwrapper

I am unable to get pyenv-virtualenvwrapper plugin to work on my Ubuntu host.
I have pyenv, virtualenvwrapper, and pyenv-virtualenvwrapper plugin installed (and in correct plugin directory).

1. I tried running `pyenv local 3.9.17`, then `python --version` shows 3.9.17
2. I then try to run `mkvirtualenv project` and then `python --version` shows wrong version

I also tried `pyenv shell 3.9.17` before creating the env, same results. Even `pyenv global 3.9.17` wont work in my vitual env. Note: I have been `source ~/.bashrc` every time I make a change in it.
The github for pyenv-virtualenvwrapper says this:

> Using pyenv virtualenvwrapper To setup a virtualenvwrapper into your
> shell, just run pyenv virtualenvwrapper. For example,
>
> $ pyenv virtualenvwrapper or, if you favor virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh,
>
> $ pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy

Tried that, same results. Here is the bottom of my `~/.bashrc`

```
# Python3 virtualenvwrapper
#export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
#export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/projects
#source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
#source $HOME/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python

#pyenv
#export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pyenv/libexec"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
command -v pyenv >/dev/null || export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

#pyenv-virtualenvwrapper plugin
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"
#pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy
pyenv virtualenvwrapper

# Rust stuff
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

Why wont this work? Ideally I want to create the `.python-version` file in my repo, and then any time I `workon project` then it will use the correct python version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to get this to work. I found this [github markdown file](https://gist.github.com/gsong/d350274d96ef83ea48773ea6ef33ab0d) that details how to properly set this up. No where else were these instructions clear to me. Here they are below, I adjusted a few things, naming conventions, and set up env configurations in the `~/.bashrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`.

1. Completely remove pyenv, virtualenvwrapper. Update your `~/.bashrc` to remove any settings referencing these.

```
sudo apt-get remove pyenv
rm -rf ~/.pyenv
sudo apt-get remove virtualenvwrapper
```

2. Install [pyenv][] using [pyenv-installer][]:

   ```bash
   curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
   ```
3. Activate pyenv for Terminal:

   ```bash
   echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
4. Exit and restart Terminal.
5. Install Python:

   ```bash
   pyenv install <some version>
   pyenv global <some version> system
   ```
6. Exit and restart Terminal.
7. Verify that you are now using the version of Python you just installed:

   ```bash
   python --version
   ```
8. Install [pyenv-virtualenvwrapper][]:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper.git ~/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper
   ```
9. Activate pyenv-virtualenvwrapper for Terminal:

   ```bash
   echo 'export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE="$WORKON_HOME"' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
10. Exit and restart Terminal.
11. Now create the virtualenvwrapper using pyenv:

    ```bash
    mkdir $HOME/YOURGITHUBDIRECTORYORFOLDERLOCATION
    mkvirtualenv somename -a $HOME/YOURGITHUBDIRECTORYORFOLDERLOCATION
    ```

Now when I do `workon` it shows the correct version and the connects me to the specific directory (git repo directory) that the project is in. Very useful!

Not sure if `pyenv global <some version> system` was needed. I was able to set this back to the original python version the system was using and it did not affect the pyenv-virtualenvwrapper env I set up.

NOTE: If you want to change pyenv versions for an active project, you cant, you have to create a new one with the specific version you want.